# C# How to delete XML/HTML comments with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

The fragment below doesn't work for me.

```
fragment = Regex.Replace(fragment, "<!--.*?-->", String.Empty , RegexOptions.Multiline  );
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change it to [`RegExOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28VS.71%29.aspx) instead and it'll work just fine.
When not in Singleline mode, the dot matches any character, *except* newline.

Note that `Singleline` and `Multiline` are not mutually exclusive. They do two separate things. To quote MSDN:

> **Multiline mode**. Changes the meaning of
>   ^ and $ so they match at the beginning
>   and end, respectively, of any line,
>   and not just the beginning and end of
>   the entire string.
>
> **Single-line mode**. Changes
>   the meaning of the dot (.) so it
>   matches every character (instead of
>   every character except \n).

Other people have already suggested the HTML Agility Pack. I just felt you should have an explanation on why your Regex wouldn't work :)

Comment: Yes, it works. At first I didn't provide the third parameter and it didn't work and I  thought RegExOptions.SingleLine is implied, but looks like Multiline is default.

Comment: Singleline and Multiline are not opposites, no matter what the names seem to imply. Both options are off by default, and setting one has no effect on the other.  Singleline changes the behavior of the dot metacharacter, and Multiline changes the behavior of the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: @Alan M: indeed, my answer was poorly worded in that respect. I've updated it a little.

Answer (score 9):

Please don't use regular expressions to work with markup languages - you need to use a better tool that is built for that kind of job.

Use the [Html Agiliy Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) instead.  I even found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/smourier/archive/2003/06/04/8265.aspx) in which a reader (named Simon Mourier) comments with a function that uses the Html Agility Pack to remove comments from a document:

> **Simon Mourier** said:
>
> This is a sample code to remove
> comments:
>
> ```
> static void Main(string[] args) 
> { 
>   HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); 
>   doc.Load("filewithcomments.htm"); 
>   doc.Save(Console.Out); // show before 
>   RemoveComments(doc.DocumentNode); 
>   doc.Save(Console.Out); // show after 
> } 
>
> static void RemoveComments(HtmlNode node)
> {
>     if (!node.HasChildNodes)
>     {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     for (int i=0; i<node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
>     {
>         if (node.ChildNodes[i].NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Comment)
>         {
>             node.ChildNodes.RemoveAt(i);
>             --i;
>         }
>     }
>
>     foreach (HtmlNode subNode in node.ChildNodes)
>     {
>         RemoveComments(subNode);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I saw the similar comment of yours in other thread.I am not convinced why I should use a better tool for occasional Web scraping extracting  hrefs between start and end marker on html page some of them commented.

Comment: Andrew is right. You cannot parse [X][HT]ML with regex, unless (a) you know in advance that a very restricted and fixed set of content is being used or (b) you don't mind lots of mistakes in your results. Parsing comments is less likely to break than parsing links, since there is much more variability in formatting for links, but it's still unreliable.

Comment: The code sample doesn't work. You can't modify the nodes while enumerating over the collection

Answer (score 2):

This is the top Google result for stripping comments via C#, and here's my HtmlAgilityPack code for doing this.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument
                           {
                               OptionFixNestedTags = true,
                               OptionOutputAsXml = true
                           };
        doc.LoadHtml(str);

        // Script comments from the document. 
        if (doc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()");
            if (nodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode node in from cmt in nodes
                                          where (cmt != null
                                                 && cmt.InnerText != null
                                                 && !cmt.InnerText.ToUpper().StartsWith("DOCTYPE"))
                                                 && cmt.ParentNode != null
                                          select cmt)
                {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                }
            }
        }
```

This works correctly at stripping comments, and ignores the doctype which is treated as a comment by HtmlAgilityPack.

While regex does work in controlled conditions. If you're processing HTML from the wild web then I'd recommend using HtmlAgilityPack. The HTML that is out there is very unpredictable, and regex will break.

Answer (score -1):

This one works for me:

```
<!--(\n|.)*-->
```

But I think you could use normal XML document for the XML or otherwise [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) for HTML. Highly **not** recommending to parse markup using RegEx.

Comment: You should put a non-greedy quantifier on your multiplier, ie. `<!--(\n|.)*?-->` Also, this problem can be solved by simply adding the SingleLine flag which modifies . to accept newlines too..

Comment: @Matthew. Yes. I agree. You theoretically are correct. But I tried the SingleLine flag and it doesn't change the result. Also both non-greedy and greedy work. Tested using radsoftware.com.au/?from=RegexDesigner

Comment: You should never use `(\n|.)*` as it is not precise, extremely inefficient due to heavy backtracking it involves, and is redundant because the mere `.` with `(?s)` or `RegexOptions.Singleline` does the job in a more efficient built-in manner. A lot of issues have already been reported due to the usage of this misfortunate pattern. Please consider removing the post, or change the solution.