# Remove comments from an XML file with double dashes --

Tags: c#, xml

How can I remove invalid xml comments that contain double dashes(`--`) from an xml file?

I'm trying to load the xml file, but it is failing. These comments make the xml invalid. The xml comes from a vendor.

I tried removing these based on approaches from other posts, but I was not successful. Here is an example of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--MAIN VARIABLES-->
<content type="screwed">
<!--KEEP 19-39 -- SEE HELP.TXT AND THE VIDEO TUTORIALS FOR MORE INFO -->
<!--REGULAR/NON-Regular EXAMPLE --><SomeTag somefile="test.txt3" Name="test"/>
<!-- -->
</content>
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
string xmlDocFile = "c:\server\test.xml";

XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.IgnoreComments = true;
readerSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;
readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlDocFile, readerSettings);
XmlDocument myXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDoc.Load(reader);
myXmlDoc.Save(xmlDocFile);
```

Comment: As you point out this is invalid XML, so anything designed to handle XML is going to struggle.  If you can go back the vendor and let them know their data's not working.  If that's not an option you'll need to treat it like a text file and use a regex to remove the double dashes between comments (or all comments), then play with the XML as normal.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304052/c-sharp-how-to-delete-xml-html-comments-with-regular-expression for more info on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using `XmlReader`, parse xml file and filter comments using regexp.

```
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
System.IO.StreamReader file= new System.IO.StreamReader(xmlDocFile);
string validXml = Regex.Replace(file.ReadToEnd(),"<!--.*?-->","");

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(validXml);
```

Comment: The streamreader with regex replace worked, since these are small files it is pretty efficient as well.

Comment: @user1816955 - You should check the green checkmark to accept this answer if this worked for you.