# Finding text in array

Tags: c#

I'm porting a routine from C++ to C# and having a difficultly understanding why the port is failing:

I have a string array which contains content that I'm and trying to strip out.

```
    string[] aryLines = File.ReadAllLines(mstrFilename);
```

The array contains the following:

```
aryLines = new[]
{
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>",
    "<!--",
    "",
    "  File:\t\tuif.xml, User Interface",
    "  Notes:\tThis file contains the application layout and includes",
    "\t\tfor other files defining the application look and functionality.",
    "",
    "  Node:\t\tuif, Root container node",
    "  Attributes:\tid\t\t: Unique node identifier",
    "\t\tcameras\t\t: Initial camera set-up",
    " \t\tcolor_bg\t: Application background colour:",
    "\t\t\t\t\tAlpha, Red, Green, Blue",
    "\t\theight\t\t: Height of the application container",
    "\t\twidth\t\t: Width of the appplication container\t\t",
    "",
    "  Node:\t\tinclude, Includes another XML file",
    "  Attributes:\tname\t\t: Encoded path to XML file to include",
    "",
    "  History:\t2017/09/11 Created by Simon Platten",
    "// -->"
};
```

I have a method that is supposed to strip out the comments, the finding the first occurrence of `<!--` and the matching `-->`, it will then remove everything in-between.  The problem is that whilst it finds the `<!--` it doesn't find the `-->` and I do not understand why.

```
private static readonly string msrostrCmtClose = "-->";
private static readonly string msrostrCmtOpen = "<!--";

int intOpen = 0;
while((intOpen = Array.IndexOf(aryLines, msrostrCmtOpen, intOpen)) >= 0) 
{
    //Opening marker located, look for closing marker   
    int intClose = Array.IndexOf(aryLines, msrostrCmtClose, intOpen);

    if ( intClose < intOpen ) 
    {
        //Shouldn't get here!
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(intOpen);
}
```

The above routine is not complete, but watching in the debugger intClose is always -1, why?

Comment: Since the comments can span multiple lines you should probably read the file into one long string rather than a series of independent "lines". Then your logic would be MUCH cleaner.

Comment: Because you have at line 19 _// -->_ Array.IndexOf is not string.Contains

Comment: `Array.IndexOf` does an exact match of the elements in the array.  In your case, it is doing an exact match of the entire contents of the string.  What you seem to be wanting it to do is a partial match of each string element.

Comment: You'd be better off using an XML parser with DOM support. Then you could just look for comment nodes and remove them. :P

Comment: @cHao, I can't use an XML parser because of the highly customisable content, my XML supports includes, variables and macros as well as expressions.

Comment: @Yuck, I wrongly assumed because other versions of IndexOf find an index of an occurrence of the string in another that this would do the same.

Comment: @SPlatten: If it includes anything that can't be reliably parsed by an XML parser, then get rid of that `<?xml...` crap at the top of the file, cause what you have is no longer XML.

Comment: @cHao, its still XML, just more functional

Comment: @SPlatten: If it's XML, then an XML parser can parse it. Might not understand it fully without some help, but an XML parser won't choke on well-formed XML, period.

Comment: It'll be much more simpler and elegant with Regular Expressions, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304052/c-sharp-how-to-delete-xml-html-comments-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Array.IndexOf` compares each element with what you're looking for, except that what you're looking for isn't actually in the array. What's in the array is `// -->` and not just `-->`.

What you can do is create a simple function like this:

```
private int IndexOfInArray(string[] array, string elemToFind, int startIndex = 0)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i].Contains(elemToFind))
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
int intOpen = 0;
while((intOpen = IndexOfInArray(aryLines, msrostrCmtOpen, intOpen)) >= 0 ) 
{
    //Opening marker located, look for closing marker   
    int intClose = IndexOfInArray(aryLines, msrostrCmtClose, intOpen);
    if (intClose < intOpen) 
    {
        //Shouldn't get here!
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(intOpen);
}
```

You'll probably have to set the `intOpen` to `intClose` or just `intOpen++` to not get the same result forever.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem now, thanks to the suggestions in the comments, the new parser looks like this:

```
    string strXML = File.ReadAllText(mstrFilename);

    int intOpen = 0;
    while( (intOpen = strXML.IndexOf(msrostrCmtOpen, intOpen)) >= 0 ) {
    //Opening marker located, look for closing marker   
            int intClose = strXML.IndexOf(msrostrCmtClose, intOpen);

            if ( intClose < intOpen ) {
    //Shouldn't get here!
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(intOpen);
        }
```

Comment: @Rufus, Take a closer look, the original was reading the data into an array of strings instead of just a single string.

Comment: Yes, I understand that...I was prompting you to actually answer the question so others can learn from it - like, describe what the problem was and how you solved it. :)

Comment: Isn’t it obvious the issue was because of my misunderstanding of index of